# Integral $\int{\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{2x^2+\sin^2(x)}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help with this integral:

$$I=\int{\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{2x^2+\sin^2(x)}dx}$$

I was given this integral in a Calculus worksheet, and I've tried every technique I know, specifically substitutions that just seem to make the integral harder. For reference, I am a first year Math student.

I just thought it wouldn't have a closed form but according to WolframAlpha the integral is
$$ I=- \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2}x\csc(x))}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$

Edit: For instance, making the substitution $t = \tan(x)$, yielding
$$ \int{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\arctan^2(t)}{1+t^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}}}{2\arctan^2(t)(1+t^2)+t^2}}dt $$

I have achieved similar results with $t=\sin(x)$, $t=\cos(x)$, and that is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Please edit and add your efforts to the question

Comment: Try dividing both numerator and denominator by $\sin^2 x$ before substituting. Pretty sure this works.

Comment: You can try Weierstrass substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral

$$I = \int{\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{2x^2+\sin^2x}}\,dx$$

can be solved by dividing through by $\sin^2 x$ so that

$$I = \int{\frac{x\cot x\csc x-\csc x}{1 + (\sqrt2x\csc x)^2}}\,dx\,.$$

Letting $u=\sqrt2x\csc x$ implies that

$$du = \sqrt2(\csc x - x\cot x\csc x)\ dx\,,$$

and so

$$\begin{aligned}
I &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int{\frac{du}{1 + u^2}}
\\ \\ &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan u + C
\\ \\ &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(\sqrt2x\csc x) + C\,.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x \cos x-\sin x}{2 x^{2}+\sin ^{2} x} d x &=\int \frac{\frac{x \cos x-\sin x}{x^{2}}}{2+\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2}} d x \\
&=\int \frac{d\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)}{2+\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x \sqrt{2}}\right)+C
\end{aligned}